# Проблема с кодировкой при чтении/записи из/в бинарныйл файл

Tags: кодировка, qt, c++

При записи в файл и последующем чтении Русский символа обозначаются черными ромбиками, с латинскими всё нормально.
Открываю файл следующем образом:

```
FILE* file = fopen(fileName, "wb");
```

Пишу в файл следующим образом:

```
fwrite(&region, sizeof(region), 1, file);
```

Где region структура. Копирую QString в string следующем образом. Думаю именно здесь проблема.

```
strcpy(region.name, this->getRegion(i)->getName().toLocal8Bit().data());
```

Есть у кого какие идеи?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы упомянули, что используете Qt. Так вот, я вам хочу сказать, что в Qt около 400 классов и 6000 методов (если мне не изменяет память). Среди этих классов так же присутствуют такие как QFile, QDataStream, QIODevice, которые имеют встроенные механизмы для оптимальной работы с другими классами Qt, в частности QString. Было бы просто замечательно, если бы вы использовали эти классы и их методы для работы с файлами, так как это позволит достичь максимальной продуктивности от использования Qt, а именно - кроссплатформенности и избавит вас, а так же тех кто будет ваш код поддерживать, от головных проблем при поиске ошибок.
Не говоря о том, что это логичней и подчас проще, чем совмещать код с использованием Qt, который написан на C++ для C++ и функции fopen, fwrite из библиотеки stdio, которые в общем-то даже и не из С++, а из С.

Comment: спасибо. я это и так прекрасно понимаю. просто не было времени изучать сохранение при помощи Qt. Так на С было уже готовое решение. Хотя тут то и переписывать нечего...

Comment: Да там изучения 5 минут. Открыл документацию, глазами пробежался, примеры глянул, все, дело в шляпе. Не нужно песчаные замки строить из С, С++ и Qt, тогда жизнь будет гораздо проще.